# ThreeJS: Getting world coordinates from camera view

Tags: three.js

I want to animate a Plane vertices to fill the screen. (Vertices as this is the effect I want, I'm hoping to animate each vertex with a short delay to then fill the screen)

As a proof of concept, I've got a vertex to animate off to a random point, using the function below -

```
tileClick() {
var geo = this.SELECTED.geometry;
var mat = this.SELECTED.material as THREE.MeshBasicMaterial;
TweenMax.TweenLite.to(geo.vertices[0], 0.3, {x: -5, y:5, onUpdate: () =>{
    mat.needsUpdate = true;
    geo.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    geo.elementsNeedUpdate = true;

  }, ease: TweenMax.Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.5)});
}
```

However, now I need to work out the points of the current view of the camera. pseudo code: `camera.view.getBoundingClientRect();`

Plnkr of WIP - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Jm4D2zgLtiKBGghC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you need is [`THREE.Vector3.unproject`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Vector3.unproject). With this method, you can set the vector to `x, y, z` in screen coordinates, and it'll return `x, y, z` in world coordinates:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
var zNearPlane = -1;
var zFarPlane = 1;

// Top left corner
vector.set( -1, 1, zNearPlane ).unproject( camera );

// Top right corner
vector.set( 1, 1, zNearPlane ).unproject( camera );

// Bottom left corner
vector.set( -1, -1, zNearPlane ).unproject( camera );

// Bottom right corner
vector.set( 1, -1, zNearPlane ).unproject( camera );
```

Notice that all inputs are in the `[-1, 1]` range:

- x:-1 = left side of screen
- x: 1 = right side of screen
- y: 1 = top
- y:-1 = bottom
- z: 1 = far plane
- z: -1 = near plane

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply @Marquizzo! It's almost right, however if you move the camera before clicking a tile it doesn't really work - https://next.plnkr.co/edit/8xfM5A1NjFV0r2t6?preview (scroll using the white bar at the top)

Comment: Ah, that's because the tile has also been translated in the x-axis when you build it with `let pos = (tileWidth + spacer) * this.tiles.length;` So not only are you changing the vertices' local position, but this also gets added on top of the translation. That's why you see them travel to the right. If you tell a vertex to go to `10`, but the tile has been translated by `5`, it'll end up at `15`. You're just going to have to subtract its x-translation value... Or you could just animate `tile.scale()` for simplicity's sake!

Comment: It's just an alternative suggestion. 'tile.scale.set(2,2,2)' would make the tile twice as big without you having to re-calculate the corner positions.

Comment: I'm confused by the .scale() solution, are you saying instead of animating the vertices? Then it wouldn't still follow/fll the camera view?

Comment: I've updated the plnkr, https://next.plnkr.co/edit/8xfM5A1NjFV0r2t6 I've subscracting the x-translation value, which does start to work, although the tile 'freak' out when too close to the camera, I tried doing something like - `this.SELECTED.position.z = this.SELECTED.position.z = -0.01;` but that didn't really work....