# Three.js: How can I find the camera's current plane

Tags: three.js

In `three.js`, when we define the camera we use something like  `camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, near, far);` If the object is moved outside the bounds set by the two planes, `far` and `near` then it is clipped.
Suppose now I rotate the object and I zoom in/out.

How can I find the current plane my camera is on please? I am learning `three.js`, hence I dont know If I am explaining this clear enough.

I thought that it was `camera.position.z` that would give me this info. In fact, I think it gives the correct value when my camera looks down the `z-axis`. However when I rotate by 90 degrees, (effectively moving my camera on the `x-axis`) the value of `camera.position.z` changes by a lot.

I have added a graph in case it helps. The plane defined by the blue outline cuts through the data and is parallel to the `far` and `near` planes. As I zoom in and out, I am moving the plane forward and backward, right? Do I understand this correct or I have totally missed it? I would like to know the value (a float between `far` and `near`) indicating how far that blue plane is from the camera. If you rotate that distance shouldn't change
[image]

My end goal is to be able to find-out how close the scene is to the viewer. If it gets too close then I will be adding some more elements to the scene. If it is too far these elements will be removed.

Comment: What do you mean its current plane? "Plane" in this context doesn't make a lot of sense, what's the output you're expecting? A `Vector3`, or 4 points that make a plane?

Comment: Hello, @Aenaon, I believe I've already answered a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50805043/2608515 Basically if you use a Vector3 with `(-1, 1, 0)` you'll get the top-left corner, halfway between the near and far planes. You could repeat this step 4 times to get the 4 corners of the blue box. `(1, 1, 0)` is top-right corner, etc.

Comment: Ah, ok! Yes, I got it, thanks it helps a lot